# std::auto_ptr<T> Usage

Tags: c++, stl, auto-ptr

I've read a reasonable amount in decent textbooks about the auto_ptr class.  While I understand what it is, and how it gets you around the problem of getting exceptions in places like constructors, I am having trouble figuring out when someone would actually use it.

An auto_ptr can only hold a single type (no array new[] initialization is supported).  It changes ownership when you pass it into functions or try and duplicate it (it's not a reference counting smart pointer).

What is a realistic usage scenario for this class give its limitations?  It seems like most of the textbook examples of its use are reaching because there isn't even a reason to be using a pointer over a stack variable in most of the cases...

Anyway, I'll stop my rant - but if you can provide a short example/description or a link to a good usage scenario for this I'd be grateful.  I just want to know where I should use it in practice in case I come across the situation - I like to practice what I learn so I remember it.

Comment: If you have a class which manages its own, large, dynamic member, then rather than `delete`ing the member in the destructor, you better wrap it in an auto_ptr. That also makes copying by const-reference impossible, which is a good thing. If the type is dynamic, a factory may return the member by `auto_ptr`. It's not entirely useless!

Comment: Your books probably use trivial objects wrapped in an `auto_ptr` to demonstrate usage. In real code, objects may not be so trivial, I wouldn't discount immediately...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll give you a short example for a good usage. Consider this:

```
auto_ptr<SomeResource> some_function() {
    auto_ptr<SomeResource> my_ptr = get_the_resource();

    function_that_throws_an_exception();

    return my_ptr;
}
```

The function that raises an exception would normally cause your pointer to be lost, and the object pointed to would not be deleted. With the `auto_ptr` this can't happen, since it is destroyed when it leaves the frame it was created, if it hasn't been assigned (for example with `return`).

Comment: Basically you are taking about transfer of ownership. Any situation where you would like to transfer the ownership of an object std::auto_ptr is great as it not only makes the transfer exception safe but the use of auto_ptr is a way of documenting the transfer.

Answer (score 4):

`auto_ptr` has been deprecated in the now finalized C++11 standard. Some of the replacements are already available through TR1 or the [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm) libraries. Examples are `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` (`scoped_ptr` in boost).

Comment: Thanks for the info, it's nice to know that they're updating the smart pointers in the new standard :)

Comment: `scoped_ptr` and `unique_ptr` are slightly different though.  `scoped_ptr` can't be returned from function, nor do I think it can be moved (in C++11 parlance).  `unique_ptr` requires the move semantics of C++11.  But if you just need to hold a reference in a function, they're interchangeable.